# AttachFile locks attachment for deleting on Windows XP

Tags: jira

I'd been working on a plugin when I discovered this. I can't say for sure if this behavior happened before or not on my machine (it doesn't on our test server, a Linux box), but after attaching a file, I can't delete it until the server restarts. I can't delete through the UI or by manually navigating to the server directory and trying to delete from there.

Has anyone ever encountered this before? Could it be something environmental on my box??

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it's a permission issue in that folder, which allows your JIRA user (a user under which privileges JIRA instance runs) to create files, but not to delete them (or something even more fun) :) Try deleting the temp folder (where your uploaded attachments reside) and recreate it again, adding your JIRA web user to the access list for that folder.

The workaround to delete files, when some other process is holding a lock on the file, without having to terminate that process, is to use [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/). But be warned, when Unlocker unlocks a file it does that in a way which does not notify the lock holder that the file has been unlocked by force. That means that the lock holder still thinks it holds the lock on the open file which it doesn't (the file handle is invalid). That means that some applications might crash due to unexpected state of the supposedly open file. Btw, I've been using Unlocker since forever and it rarely caused any crashes, but it's better to be warned.